# When user reply the SMS with 'Lastname', we need to create lead record in MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

How to create lead record when user reply with 'Arun'(Lastname) in

mobileconnect in marketing salesforce.

Below is the sample code but it doesn't work. please help on this.

```
%%[ var @mn set @mn = AttributeValue("LastName") ]%%

%%[ var @id
set @id=CreateSalesforceObject("Account", 2, "LastName", %%=v(@mn)=%%, "Email__c", "Cruz@mail.com")
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some issues with your AMPScript.  The `%%=v()=%%` is not needed inside an AMPScript block.  Should be something like this:

```
%%[ 

 var @mn, @id 
 set @mn = MSG(0).NOUN(0) 
 set @id = CreateSalesforceObject("Account", 2, "LastName", @mn, "Email__c", "Cruz@mail.com")

]%%
```

The `MSG(0).NOUN(0)` could also be `MSG(0).VERB` depending on your use case.

Reference:

[AMPScript Variables for use with Mobile Messages](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_variables_for_use_with_mobile_messages/)

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for your quick reply.

Process is like user will send "Yes" to short code and a reply will come "Please send your Lastname" once user send lastname(Adam) we need to add this in createsalesforceobject dynamically as a "Adam" and needs to create Account record in Sales Cloud.

Thanks,
Rajesh